# Programmatically change report path from Report Viewer Web Part Sharepoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've added **Report Viewer Web Part** to page with report path URL.
Now I just want to get that Report Viewer Web Part from SharePoint page and **change its report path URL property programmatically using c# or jquery**.

Can anybody know How to achieve this? thank you.

Comment: see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.webparts.aspx .         private static void GetWebParts()
{   using (SPSite site = new SPSite("<YOUR SITE URL>"))
  {    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())      {      SPFile file = web.GetFile("default.aspx");       using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
      {        foreach (WebPart wp in wpm.WebParts)
        {          Console.WriteLine("Web part: {0}", wp.Title); }}}}}

Comment: Get the report viewer web part title using the GetLimitedWebPartManager API as the first part.

Comment: Thanks SaMolPP for reply. Yes I'm able to get my report viewer web part using  SPLimitedWebPartManager class. But the problem is that how to change its report path URL?